# Error Spring Boot Kubernetes ConfigMaps

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

tengo un problema con la libreria de spring boot kubernetes. El tema, es que poseo un configmaps con 2 properties, pero al momento de levantar el pod en kubernetes, spring toma los properties que ya vienen en el pod y no la del configmap, pero si configuro el configmap con un solo properties, funciona perfecto.

Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema ??? Puede ser problema de la librería de spring ???

**Configmaps:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Bootstrap:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Da clic en [edit] y remplaza las imágenes  por el código en texto y más detalles que nos puedan ayudar a resolver tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

sería bueno comentar el nombre de la librería exacta que estas usando op un link a la librería para poder saber cúal usas.

Voy a asumir que se trata de: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/

Parece que te está faltando esta dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

en tu archivo `pom.xml`.